# Commutative rings whose non-trivial ideals are maximal

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

It is well known that a local ring is a ring containing only one maximal ideal. I was wondering if there is a characterization (or any information) of the commutative rings such that all their non-trivial ideals are maximal.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you want all prime ideals to be maximal? That's something interesting, although I don't know if I would call it opposite.

Comment: Yes maybe opposite its confusing, but i do not know how to call such a ring.
There are rings such that all prime ideals are maximal, for example $\mathbb{Z}$ or any Dedekind domain.

Comment: Maybe you mean rings of [Krull dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_dimension) 0? If you assume it to be Noetherian, then you're basically talking about [Artinian rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin_ring). (where I interpret "such that all their non-trivial ideals" as "such that all their prime ideals")

Comment: If all non-trivial ideals are maximal, then for any element $a$, we must have $(a) = (a^2)$ (since $(a)\supset (a^2)$ and $(a^2)$ is maximal or trivial). So there exists an element $r$ such that $a= ra^2$. Thus, $a(1-ra) = 0$ implies that either $a$ is a zero divisor, or it is a unit. See [this question on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/42647/rings-in-which-every-non-unit-is-a-zero-divisor)

Comment: Just a thought: in the case when $A$ contains a non-zero nilpotent, by hypothesis the nilradical of $A$ is maximal ideal, hence there is exactly one prime ideal of $A$. Since all non-trivial ideals are maximal (hence prime), this would mean that there is exactly one non-trivial ideal of A.

Comment: @Sam I was actually thinking on all non-trivial ideals, the rings you are mentioning are the Dedekind Domains (in the case that they are also integrally closed).

Comment: @Sam Thanks for indicating me that question in mathoverflow. It gives a necessary condition for a ring with the properties i was asking.

Comment: @Sam Maybe we are interpreting something differently, but I don't see why $(a^2)=(a)$. In $F[x]/(x^2)$, $(x)\neq \{0\}$ but $(x^2)=\{0\}$.

Comment: @Prism That's a great observation, and I hope you don't mind that I cited it as some inspiration in my solution. You showed that if $Nil(R)\neq 0$ then $R$ has exactly one nontrivial ideal, and then I realized that if $Nil(R)=0$ you have exactly two nontrivial ideals :)

Comment: @rschwieb: Haha I would be honoured :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to characterize a ring $R$ whose nontrivial ideals are maximal is this way:

> $R$ is a ring with finite composition length and that length is at most 2.

Another obvious way is

> $R$ is a ring in which the maximal and minimal ideals coincide.

In particular, $R$ is a "very small" Artinian ring.

In the case they have composition length 1, you have a field. An easy example of a nonfield ring of composition length 2 is $F[x]/(x^2)$ for a field $F$. Yet another example is $F\times K$ for two fields $F,K$.

An interesting way to analyze the nonfield case was brought up by Prism in the comments: if $Nil(R)\neq 0$, then since $R$ is Artinian, $Nil(R)=J(R)$ is the unique minimal and unique maximal ideal of $R$.

If $Nil(R)=\{0\}$ then we have a commutative semisimple Artinian ring, i.e. a finite product of fields. It's easy to see that $R$ would have to be a product of exactly two fields, $F$ and $K$, so that $F\times K$ would have exactly these nontrivial ideals: $F\times\{0\}$ and $\{0\}\times K$.

So a good third thing to add to our list would be:

> $R$ is a field, a product of two fields, or else is a [uniserial ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniserial_ring) with exactly one nontrivial ideal.

---

If you are curious about noncommutative rings as well (and we talk about all nontrival *right ideals* being maximal), then $M_2(F_2)$, the $2\times 2$ matrix ring over the field of $2$ elements is an easy example of a (noncommutative) ring with composition length 2.

---

About saying "the opposite of a local ring." I think a much more natural candidate for the "opposite" of a local ring is a ring which has a unique minimal ideal. Among commutative rings, these are exactly the subdirectly irreducible rings.

There is an interesting connection when the conditions are combined and the descending chain condition is thrown in: For a commutative local artinian ring $R$,  $R$ has a unique minimal ideal iff its ideals form a chain.

Comment: Very informative! (+1) I learnt a lot from this answer. :)

Comment: @prism Happy it helped!

Answer (score 1):

In any ring $R$, $R$ itself is a nonmaximal ideal. Assuming you meant to exclude that case: if every ideal of $R$ is maximal, then in particular $\{0\}$ is a maximal ideal, and so $R$ is a field.

Comment: I was thinking on the non-trivial ideals. I think it is better to edit the question.  Thanks